# User cannot write to directory after granting permission with setfacl

Tags: acl

EDIT: I forgot to add `/mnt/storage` has been mounted using **mergerfs** (pooling 2 drives which are formatted as ext4)

I am running Lubuntu 22.04.2 and have run the following commands (note the user `radarr` belongs to the group `media`):

```
sudo setfacl -Rm  u:radarr:rwx /mnt/storage/Films
sudo setfacl -dRm u:radarr:rwx /mnt/storage/Films
sudo setfacl -Rm  g:media:rwx  /mnt/storage/Films
sudo setfacl -dRm g:media:rwx  /mnt/storage/Films
```

EDIT: this is the output of `getfacl /mnt /mnt/storage /mnt/storage/Films`:

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: mnt
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

# file: mnt/storage
# owner: ali
# group: root
user::rwx
user:sonarr:rwx
user:radarr:r-x
group::rwx
group:media:r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x

# file: mnt/storage/Films
# owner: ali
# group: ali
user::rwx
user:radarr:rwx
group::rwx
group:media:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:radarr:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:media:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

However, when I test write permissions using:

```
sudo -u radarr test -w /mnt/storage/Films; echo "$?"
```

this returns 1 instead of 0, even after rebooting, so I think I have misunderstood something. Is there an additional command required that I have missed?

Comment: What is `/mnt/storage`? How is it mounted? Also, please [edit] your question and add the output of `getfacl /mnt /mnt/storage`.

Comment: The user `radarr` probably does not have execution (search) permission for `/mnt` and/or `/mnt/storage`: `sudo -u radarr bash -c 'test -x /mnt; echo $?; test -x /mnt/storage; echo $?'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an oversight on my part: I had failed to include the option `posix_acl=true` when calling mergerfs in `/etc/fstab`. Adding this option and rebooting has fixed the issue.